# Python поиск минимума рекурсивным методом

Tags: python, рекурсия, max, min

Не могу найти ошибку.
Написал такой же код для поиска максимума, только изменил '<' на '>' и все работает корректно...

Есть какие-то идеи ?

```py
def min(list):
    if len(list) == 0:
        return
    else:
        print(list)
        sub_min = min(list[1:])
        print(sub_min)
        return list[0] if list[0] < sub_min else sub_min

print(min([15, 2, 7, 5, 11]))
```

output:

```
[15, 2, 7, 5, 11]
[2, 7, 5, 11]
[7, 5, 11]
[5, 11]
[11]
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: Очевидно, в какой-то момент `sub_min` оказывается `None`, а `None` всегда меньше любого числа. Поэтому с максимумом этот код работать будет (числа всегда больше чем `None`), а с минимумом всегда будет возвращаться `None`

Comment: @andreymal точно, спасибо, очень глупая ошибка, прописал базовый случай учитывая этот недостаток :
`if len(list) == 2:
        return list[0] if list[0] < list[1] else list[1]`
теперь все работает отлично

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в базовом методе

```py
def min(list):
    if len(list) == 2:
        return list[0] if list[0] < list[1] else list[1]
    else:
        print(list)
        sub_min = min(list[1:])
        print(sub_min)
        return list[0] if list[0] < sub_min else sub_min

print(min([15, 2, 7, 5, 11]))

Output:
2
```

Comment: Теперь не работает `print(min([1]))`